# Nativescript tab view change doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm trying to change tabs manually but I found a bug. So basically there is an issue when tabs don't change even when tab index has changed. I have created a nativescript playground app where you can see the problem. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=VYfreA&v=2 To recreate the issue, all you have to do is press `Field` tab, then `Go to profile` button then again `field` tab and then you will see when pressing `Go to profile` button tab will not change.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a bug but absolutely an expected behaviour. Your binding on `selectedIndex` is one way, you are not monitoring changes from the TabView.

So when you navigated to Filed tab by tapping on tab header, value of `selectedIndex` remains 2. Clicking on GO TO PROFILE button would try to change the value to 2, but the variable value is already 2 so the change detection won't happen.

To handle this scenario, you will have to listen for `selectedIndexChange` event and update the variable constantly.

```
            <TabView :selectedIndex="selectedIndex" @selectedIndexChange="selectedIndex = $event.value">
                <TabViewItem title="home">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button text="go to fields" @tap="selectedIndex = 1"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </TabViewItem>

                <TabViewItem title="Field">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button text="go to profile" @tap="selectedIndex = 2"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </TabViewItem>

                <TabViewItem title="profile">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button text="go to home" @tap="selectedIndex = 0"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </TabViewItem>
            </TabView>
```

Comment: This not that. Test this variant - not work transition to  home page.
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Jg7PvP

Comment: You are also pointing the same issue, property change won't be recognised until the value is updated to a different one from previous value. I had tested the above code works on my end.

Comment: Ok, it is working but i don't know why. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Jg7PvP&v=2

Comment: Thank you for this information. This should be in the documentation.